# Tkinter - winfo_height() always returns 1

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, height

I have a function that gets called by clicking a button called *expand_keyword*. This function expands a row of a table to show more data. The data is contained in multiple frames called *single_cve_frame*.

I'm trying to get the height of those frames by using the function `winfo_height()` but I always get returned the value '1'. I tried retrieving the value after *packing* the frame and after calling the root's function `update_idletasks()` but I get the same result. I call the function by accessing the parent of self which is the root. Here is my code:

```
def expand_keyword(self, frame: ExpandableKeywordCVEsFrame, organized_cves):
        for cve in organized_cves[keyword]['matching_cves']:
            single_cve_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(frame, fg_color = '#E1E1E1')
            ctk.CTkLabel(single_cve_frame,
                         text = cve,
                         text_color = 'black',
                         font = ('Inter', 18)
                         ).place(relx = 0.2, rely = 0.5, relwidth = 0.25, relheight = 1, anchor = 'center')
            
            single_cve_frame.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')
            print(single_cve_frame.winfo_height())
            self.master.update_idletasks()
            print(single_cve_frame.winfo_height())
```

Edit: I've noticed that The *w_info_height* values are returned before the widgets are generated on the gui. This could be the reason they are '1'. Even by setting the height of the frames statically, the values are still 1.

Comment: just use single_cve_frame.update() instead of self.master.update_idletasks()

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: @NULL Not even single_cve_frame.update() works. I've noticed that the w_info_height values are printed before the widgets are generated on the gui. Could that be the reason they are '1'?

Comment: And even by setting singular_cve_frame's height statically in its constructor, the value is still 1.